# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in 'field list'?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to do `Auth:logout();`, but im getting this error. Do i really need this column or i can avoid that?

```
Route::get('/logout', 'MainController@logout');

  public function logout(){
      Auth::logout();

      return response()->json([
        'isLoggedIn' => false
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you've deleted the `remember_token` from the `users` table. Laravel uses this field by default, so you can just add the field back to the table:

```
$table->rememberToken();
```

Of course you could override some of Laravel methods to disable this functionality, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Exactly! It is missing. :)

Comment: So, how do you change the name of this table... I have added a getRememberTokenName function to override the Auth\User class, however, on logout it is still looking for this column.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid that by using this on your User Model.

```
 /**
* Overrides the method to ignore the remember token.
*/
public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
$isRememberTokenAttribute = $key == $this->getRememberTokenName();
if (!$isRememberTokenAttribute)
{
  parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add an upgrade for your `users` table.

```
php artisan make:migration AddToTokenToUsersTable
```

A file like `database/migrations/2022_03_26_190557_add_to_token_to_users_table.php` is created. Then you edit this file like this:

```
class AddToTokenToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropRememberToken();
        });
    }
}
```

Then, just run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to 'up' function in your create_user_table migration and add

```
$table->rememberToken();
```

to the schema
remember too reset migration and carry out a fresh db:seed

Answer (score 0):

Running `php artisan migrate:fresh` solved my problem. However, I did already have the migration scripts in place, ready to be executed when I run that comand.